# Scrolling down and hold on mobile devices shows elements that are located just below viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have an element that I wish to show when the user clicks something, emerging from the bottom of the screen. To do that, I have the code here: [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arNBZa). Relevant code:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('filler')[0].addEventListener('click', e => {     
  document.getElementById('target').classList.add('targetChanged');
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.filler { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.locatedBelowViewport {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.targetChanged {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div class = "filler"></div>
  <div id = "target" class = "locatedBelowViewport"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see, when you click the first black box in the display, the red `<div>` comes out. There is nothing wrong when I tried simulating it in CodePen in my mobile device (Android device) as the "toolbar" of my Google Chrome's device does not disappear (for reference, this it the "toolbar" that I am talking about):

[image: Toolbar]

In my regular static webpage, though, scrolling down causes that to disappear and it leaves a gap on the bottom of my screen (the size of the now vanished "toolbar") and I can see the red `<div>` there when I scroll **and hold. Only scrolling does not cause this problem.**

Is there a way to work around that behaviour that does not involve preventing the "toolbar" from disappearing (I want it to disappear when users scroll down)?

Answer (score 0):

Will making the the .locatedBelowViewport taller help?

```
.locatedBelowVieport {
  height: 120%; // some number greater than 100
}
```